# Index values from table into another table

Tags: lua

I want to store the values by selecting the keys of a table into another table, for example:

```
polyline = {color="blue", thickness=2, npoints=4}

stuff = {"polyline.color":[polyline.thickness]}
print(stuff)
```

Should produce:

```
blue   2
```

However, I get the following error:

> input:3: '}' expected near ':'

Comment: Try `stuff = {polyline.color, polyline.thickness}`.

Comment: like in your previous post you're mixing Lua and JavaScript syntax. That aside the JavaScript part doesn't look right. you'd probably benefit from learning one language at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe, You're mixing in some Python syntax. Do you notice using two different (wrong) ways of accessing the values?

I guess, this is what You've meant with your snippet of Lua code:

```
polyline = {color = "blue", thickness = 2, npoints = 4}

stuff = {[polyline.color] = polyline.thickness}
for key, val in pairs(stuff) do
    print(key, val)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
local polyline = {color="blue", thickness=2, npoints=4}

local stuff = {polyline.color, polyline.thickness}
print(table.unpack(stuff))
```